# AngleSharp кодировка страницы

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Как изменить кодировку страницы, которая парсится?
Метод парсинга:

```
 public static string[] takeTemp(string page, string CSSStyle)
{
    try
    {
        var parser = new HtmlParser();
        var document = parser.Parse(page);

        var infoFromSite = document.QuerySelectorAll(CSSStyle);

        string[] tommorow = new string[infoFromSite.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < infoFromSite.Length; i++)
        {
            tommorow[i] = infoFromSite[i].TextContent;
        }

        return tommorow;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Write(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kdcak6ye(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Тип `string` содержит строку в кодировке UTF-16. Думаю, вам нужно задать нужную кодировку при _получении_ страницы, уровнем выше.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov переменная page это url/ссылка на страницу с которой парсит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov подскажите что делать?

Comment: разве `HtmlParser` из `AngleSharp` так умеет?

Comment: попробуйте парсить через `AngleSharp` они переводят в `utf-8`: `let config = Configuration().WithDefaultLoader()
let document = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(page).Result`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov строка, которая мне нужна следующего содержания "&minus;3" а парсится как "?3" и я никак не могу убрать или заменить этот знак "?".

Comment: @FoggyFinder это через AngleSharp я парсю.

Comment: тогда покажите весь код относящийся к вопросу

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решилась банально просто.

```
tommorow[i] = infoFromSite[i].TextContent.Replace("\u2212", "-");
```

Comment: Костыль... У вас могут и дальше выводиться неверно значения, везде будете `Replace` делать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в этом поле может быть только 2 типа значений, это положительной число, которое без символа и отрицательное с символом. А так согласен - костыль.